# Paypal direct payment HTML button together with IPN

Tags: php, paypal, payment, paypal-ipn

I'm using an HTML PayPal button together with IPN to achieve a direct payment on my PHP website. The IPN URL is correctly pinged but I need a way to identify the transaction, because I need to update it on my local database during the IPN call.

So my question is : is there a simple way to send a token / identifier from the HTML button and get it back on the IPN call, so that I retrieve the transaction?

If no, I guess I'll have to use the API but the code samples I found on the PayPal website confused me. I need the payment to offer both Paypal / Credit Card options to the user once he lands on the PayPal payment page. This is what they call a "Direct Payment" but is there any clear Direct Payment code samples I can use somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used the simple form to redirect customers to paypal. In this form i have a hidden input `<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="myCustomInvoiceId" />`.

After the customer finished his payment, paypal will do the IPN call including `invoice=myCustomInvoiceId`. So yes. There are plenty of variables more that paypal can include in their IPN call. See [this link](https://www.paypalobjects.com/de_DE/html/IntegrationCenter/ic_ipn-pdt-variable-reference.html) for further reading.

if i remember correctly, you can chose which variables to include in the IPN call in your merchant paypal account.